# What is the most compact, efficient and reliable way of extracting numbers from dollar amounts in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

What I'm talking about is reading a string into a Number, e.g.

`"$107,140,946"` ---> `107140946`

`"$9.99"` ---> `9.99`

Is there a better way than

```
dolstr.replace('$','');
dolstr.replace(',','');
var num = parseInt(dolstr,10);
```

???

Comment: Doesn't `parseInt()` try to return an integer?

Comment: I think you mean't `parseFloat()`

Comment: @JamesAMohler I know, but I thought it stops parsing if it finds an unexpected character

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple regex and the string's `replace` function

`parseFloat(dolstr.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ''))`

Breakdown

It replaces every instance of a character that is not a digit (0 - 9) and not a period. Note that the period must be escaped with a backwards slash.

You then need to wrap the function in `parseFloat` to convert from a string to a float.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex is much simpler to read and maintain

```
 parseFloat(dolstr.replace(/\$|,/g, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just put all of this in oneliner:

```
parseFloat(dolstr.replace('$','').split(",").join(""))
```

Notice that I do not replace the second one, because this will remove just the first ','.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming input is always correct, just keep only digits (`\d`) and the dot (`\.`) and get rid of other characters. Then run parseFloat on the result.

```
parseFloat(dolstr.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ''))
```